# Unable to Mock functions inside static method Powermock

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am writing unit test for the below code using junit and mockito

```
 public class Abc implements Runnable
    {
        private static ServerSocket server;  
        private static int port;      
        public Abc(int cPort)
        {
            port = cPort;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            init();
        }

        public static void init()
        {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(port);
                ...something...
                client.close();
                } 
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {   
                System.out.println("Exception inside init()...");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Unit test I have written

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ServerSocket.class})
public class abcTest {

    @Mock (name = "server") //same name as private var.
    ServerSocket mockServer;        
    @InjectMocks
    Abc abc;

    @Test
    public void testInit() throws Exception {
        int port = 1880;
        Socket mockClient = Mockito.mock(Socket.class);  
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ServerSocket.class).
                withArguments(anyInt()).thenReturn(mockServer);         
        abc = new Abc(port);
        Abc.init();         
        PowerMockito.verifyNew(ServerSocket.class).withArguments(port);
    }
};
```

But the  call always go to original function definition. I am using junit 4.11 with mockito 2.28.2 and powermockito 2.0.2. I'm using java after a long time. Now its feel like kind of new. Please correct me if anything wrong in the code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your `PrepareForTest` annotation
to `@PrepareForTest({Abc.class})`.

From the PowerMockito [`docu`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/2.0.2/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html):

> This annotation tells PowerMock to prepare certain classes for testing. Classes needed to be defined using this annotation are typically those that needs to be byte-code manipulated

In this case that refers to the class which creates the new instance of `ServerSocket`.
 `ServerSocket` itself is a `non-final` `public` class that does not require special handling from `PowerMockito` (instead `Mockito` can deal with this class on its own).

---

You could also change your test to do the following:

```java
@Test
public void testInit() throws Exception {
    int port = 1880;

    ServerSocket mockServer = Mockito.mock(ServerSocket.class);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(ServerSocket.class)
                .withArguments(Mockito.anyInt()).thenReturn(mockServer);

    Abc.port = port;
    Abc.init();     

    PowerMockito.verifyNew(ServerSocket.class).withArguments(port);
}
```

---

- *(This first point is unrelated to whether the test fails or succeeds)*
  I do not know why you mix object's and static method behaviour together, but I think you should change that.
  In the test instead of creatic an `ABC` object, just could just set the static port variable directly.
  Or alternatively change the whole `ABC` class into an object.
- `@InjectMocks` failed for me as there is no default constructor
  (Actually I got an error message in the console when trying to execute your code)
- Additonaly you create a new instance of ABC in your test, which would have overwritten the things done by the annotations. Also as `server` is created during the `init` call, there is no need to inject a mock for it.
- `powermockito 2.0.2` actually depends on `junit 4.12`, so I am not sure what effects downgrading to an older version might have.
- `Socket mockClient` seemed somewhat unrelated to the code your posted, so I removed it from my example in the answer, however as you use a `client` (I assume that is your `Socket`) in your code your probably need to do some mocking for that as well and provide the mock to the method accordingly.

Comment: Changing annotation and upgrading the junit version worked for me! Thanks :)